# How many positive integer solutions satisfy the condition $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 < 100$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In preparation for an upcoming test I have come across the following problem and I am looking for some help with it just in case a question of its kind comes up on a evaluation. Thanks!

> How many positive integer solutions satisfy the condition:$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 < 100$$

Comment: How many positive integers "to do the following"? Do you mean how many "satisfy the condition"?

Comment: that's the question, but I guess so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to put 4 separator between the 99 inner intervals between the 100 objects in such way that, for example starting from the left

- $y_1>1$ first group of objects
- $y_2>1$ second group of objects
- $y_3>1$ third group of objects
- $y_4>1$ fourth group of objects
- $y_5>1$ fifth group of objects

such that $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4<100$$

that is

$$\binom{99}{4}$$

Comment: why did you use  $y_5$?

Comment: @user123 it is the standard trick to guarantee that the sum $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4$ is less than 100 since $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=100$ and $y_5>1$

Comment: I am typing up an answer that I got now, do you mind telling me where I went wrong? it will take me only a few minutes to do, thanks for your submission by the way!

Comment: I have posted my answer up above, where did I go wrong?

Comment: I never thought of this. My first thought was 99 choose 3, but that would give y1+y2+y3+y4=100. but if we add y5 then that guarantees below 100. learned a lot

Comment: @SakethMalyala so this answer posted by gimusi is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Add a slack-variable $y_5$ and note that this is the same as the number of solutions to
$$
y_1+\dotsb+y_5=100;\quad y_i\geq1
$$
Using stars and bars there are
$$
\binom{100-1}{5-1}
$$
solutions.

Comment: could you explain the stars and bars a little more? and the $y_i$?

Comment: thanks for your submission btw!

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the question was:
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 4$$

There is only $1$ solution:
$$1+1+1+1 = 4$$

Now lets assume it was:
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 5$$

There are $4$ solutions:
$$1+1+1+2=5$$
$$1+1+2+1 = 5$$
$$1+2+1+1 = 5$$
$$2+1+1+1 = 5$$

Next assume it was:
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 5 $$

There are $10$ solutions:
$$1+1+1+3 = 6$$
$$1+1+2+2 = 6$$
$$1+1+3+1 = 6$$
$$1+2+2+1 = 6$$
$$1+2+1+2 = 6$$
$$1+3+1+1 = 6$$
$$2+1+1+2 = 6$$
$$2+1+2+1 = 6$$
$$2+2+1+1 = 6$$
$$3+1+1+1 = 6$$

There's a pattern:

$$n=4 \implies \binom{3}{3} = 1$$
$$n=5 \implies\binom{4}{3} = 4$$
$$n=6 \implies\binom{5}{3} = 10$$
$$n=7 \implies\binom{6}{3} = 20$$
$$n=8 \implies\binom{7}{3} = 35$$

Then by adding up all the terms up to $98$ you get the answer:
$$\sum_{i=3}^{98}\binom{i}{3} =\binom{99}{4}= 3764376$$

Indeed by [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) we have

$$\sum^n_{i=r}{i\choose r}={n+1\choose r+1} \qquad \text{ for } n,r\in\mathbb{N}, \quad n>r$$

Comment: Note that you should calculate $$\sum_{i=3}^{98}\binom{n}{3} =\binom{99}{4}$$

Comment: okay I think I will stick with your answer, thanks again!

Comment: Indeed for n=4 we have to put 3 separators in 3 slots thus (3,3)=1 with n=5 (4,3)=4 with n=5 (5,3)=10 and so on till n=99 (98,3).

Comment: okay so $\binom{99}{4}$ is the final answer

Comment: would you be able to edit my answer so its correct?

Comment: Yes I think that is so! $\binom{99}{4}$ is correct

Comment: is it not sufficient the comment above to explain?

Comment: I am a little confused where to put that in and what to change could you edit it in? or I will just go with your answer and try to learn that one

Comment: both are valid, your way to count all the possibilities also lead to the correct answer as you can see but the trick to add a dummy $y_5$ solve the OP more effectively, let me know if all is clear now

Comment: okay so both work that's great! thanks for your original answer and for editing mine, I really appreciate it!

Comment: last question  when you wrote the sum from i=3 to n, i choose 3, how did it that equal 99 choose 4?

Comment: I’ve added the source, it is a well known equality for binomial coefficient

Comment: awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $f(n)$ is the number of positive integer solutions to $y_1 + \ldots + y_4 =  n$, then 
$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty f(n) x^n = (x^1 + x^2 + \ldots)^4 = \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^4 $$

Comment: is this a complete solution? thanks for your post btw